# SKSpriteNodes spawning in the wrong place - is the game scene itself moving?

Tags: swift, sprite-kit, skspritenode, skaction, skscene

[Long post ahead.]

I'm really confused as to why this is happening.

I have a game in which sprites (SKSpriteNodes) spawn at regular-ish intervals off the right side of the screen and move to the left.

The spawning sprites are children of a 'world' SKSpriteNode, which is a child of the game scene. The world is declared here (in `didMove(to: view)`):

```
world = self.childNode(withName: "world") as! SKSpriteNode
```

The spawns are added to the 'world' like this:

```
nowSpawn.position = CGPoint(x: 350, y: 0)
world.addChild(nowSpawn)
nowSpawn.run(SKAction.moveBy(x: -1000, y: 0, duration: 10))
```

This spawn-adding is inside the function `addSpawn()` which is called in another function called `spawnDelays()` that calculates the slight variations in intervals at which to add the spawns. `spawnDelays()` is called in `didMove(to : view)`:

```
func spawnDelays () {

    let randDuration = Double(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(2))) + (universalDuration/8)
    let rerunSpawnDelays = SKAction.run{spawnDelays()}

    run(SKAction.sequence([
            SKAction.run(addSpawn),
            SKAction.wait(forDuration: Double(randDuration)),
            rerunSpawnDelays,

            ]), withKey: "spawning"
        )

    }

spawnDelays()
```

However, something weird is happening. For about the first 10-15 spawns it works as expected, with the spawns emerging from the right of the screen and moving to the left. However, soon after, the spawns start appearing further to the left (i.e. on screen), and keep appearing further to the left until they are completely off the left side of the screen.

To try and see what's going on, I've been printing the `.position` of each spawn and also of the world sprite every time a new spawn appears. However, even if the spawn is spawning in the wrong place (e.g. in the middle of the screen, whose position would be near (0,0)), the console still prints its position as being (350, 0) - i.e. the position where I add the spawns.

To check that the world sprite isn't moving, I've also been printing its position every time a spawn is spawned - and it is consistently (0.0000.., 0.0....).

My only possible explanation is that the world's parent - which is the game scene - is inching leftwards, and therefore the relative position of all the children sprites is shifted to the left. But that makes no sense.

Comment: I suggest showing more of the code. At the very least, I would be interested to see how you're treating `nowSpawn` -- what kind of variable it is & how you're creating the sprite.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your interest. I'm afraid to say that I've discovered the issue and it was completely different to what I'd expected. To create spawns, I was juggling through two arrays - spawnsToSummon and spawnsOnScreen. When adding a spawn to the scene I was adding it to spawnsOnScreen and removing it from spawnsToSummon, and vice versa when removing the spawn from screen. However, I wasn't removing the spawn's SKActions = so basically, the newly created spawns would have a queue of SKActions to complete.   Will delete this post